# Filter already output mysql data in HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have my MySQL data output into a HTML table successfully and exactly how I want it. Now I'd like to filter this data based on multiple dropdown values and a submit button. I've looked around in tutorials and other questions but can't find what I'm looking for. Here's how I output:

```
$fetchResult = "SELECT a.MembershipID, a.FirstName, a.Surname, t.RaceID, r.RaceName, t.Time, r.RaceID, r.ClubYear  
                            FROM Athlete AS a 
                            INNER JOIN Time AS t  
                                ON a.MembershipID=t.MembershipID
                            INNER JOIN Race AS r
                                ON t.RaceID=r.RaceID
                            ORDER BY a.Surname";
            $result = $mysqli->query($fetchResult);

            //Start table
            echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Surname</th>
                    <th>Race</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>Club Year</th>";

            // Loop through database
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['FirstName'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['Surname'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['RaceName'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['Time'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['ClubYear'] . '</td>';
            }

            echo "</tr></table>";
```

Now I have 4 dropdowns also populated by data from the database. What I'd like to happen is, the user picks an option between 1 and 4 dropdowns and the data in the HTML gets filtered but I can't get this to work. Here is what I have so far:

```
if (!empty($clubYear)) {
    $fetchResult = "SELECT a.MembershipID, a.FirstName, a.Surname, t.RaceID, r.RaceName, t.Time, r.RaceID, r.ClubYear  
                            FROM Athlete AS a 
                            INNER JOIN Time AS t  
                                ON a.MembershipID=t.MembershipID
                            INNER JOIN Race AS r
                                ON t.RaceID=r.RaceID
                            WHERE r.ClubYear='$clubYear'
                            ORDER BY a.Surname";
    }
    $result = $mysqli->query($fetchResult);
```

So I check to see if the dropdown is empty, if not, apply a query with a WHERE filter. This just makes the page refresh and go to a "no data received" page. Where am I going wrong? The filter should be applied based on what's been selected in the dropdown but without explicitly stating what that dropdown equals i.e= if $clubYear == "whatever", then WHERE r.ClubYear="whatever" - I'd like to just filter through passing the variable.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, if the behavior is that you want to emit *all* data to the page at first and then filter after that, your best bet is to do all of the filtering client-side.  Which means in JavaScript.  There are lots of JavaScript tools/libraries to do this.  DataTables (a jQuery plugin) is a very widely used and robust example.  Basically, since *all* of the data has already been transferred, there's no need to make more round trips to the server.

Comment: Okay thanks for the tip. I'll look into at and come back if I have any more questions.